# How can i display un image to another client

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I'm new on node.js, i'm trying to make a simple sharing picture app, and my problem is: I would like that when a client uploads an image to display it on its screen, it is displayed at the same time on the screen of the other clients, when a client loads an image to display on its screen, it works very well, but it is not displayed in the screen of other clients.

Here is my HTML code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script> 

    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
    socket.on('addimage',function(msg,base64image){

           $('#img')
                    .attr('src', base64image)
                    .width(800)
                    .height(400);
        });

    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#img')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)
                    .width(800)
                    .height(400);

                 socket.emit('user image', e.target.result);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
</script>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Jhh</title>



<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div><input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" /></div></b>
   <div><img id="img" src="" /></div> 
</body>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>

</html>
```

And here is my server.js code :

```js
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
fs.readFile('./index.html', 'utf-8', function(error, content) {
res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
res.end(content);
});
});


var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);



io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
   socket.on('user image',function (image)
    {
     io.sockets.emit('addimage', 'Image recu :',image);

    });
});

app.get('/',function (req,res) {
    res.render('index');
})

server.listen(8080,function () {
    console.log('listen port 8080')
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Emitting consider sending Object like this

```
io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
   socket.on('user image',function (image){
      io.sockets.emit('addimage', {'src' :image});
   });
});
```

And load Jquery and sockets.io.js before using it into script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
      <meta charset=utf-8 />
      <title>Jhh</title>
      <style>
       article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
       menu, nav, section { display: block; }
      </style>
   </head>
    <body>
        <div><input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" /></div></b>
        <div><img id="img" src="" /></div> 
        <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script> 

         var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

         socket.on('addimage',function(msg){
            //reading src property from msg as per changes
            $('#img')
                .attr('src', msg.src)
                .width(800)
                .height(400);
});

function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#img')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(800)
                .height(400);
             socket.emit('user image', e.target.result);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
  </script>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thaank you soo much sir, finally everything works well ! :)

Comment: You are welcome , please accept my answer and give upvote , thanks

Comment: Hey sir, if i can ask you something else, now i'm trying to share the image with different clients using other computers, how can i do it, since i can't share the URL of the file ? i heard about something called Blob but i'dont know much about it, any help would be great :)

Comment: I didn't understood , what do you mean by sharing image with other computers , what exactly you are trying to achieve ?? can you be brief about the problem

Comment: The image that i uploaded with the input, I want to be able to share it with other users connected through separate computers (in a local network), I heard about a Blob format that allows to send any file properly, but I do not know more about it